# I dropped my bike and now it won't start

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting, ignition, katana

I have a Suzuki GSX600F Katana. Yesterday, I changed the clutch lever on the handlebar and left the key on. I had to push start my bike.

After getting it started, I left it in first gear, and let go of the clutch lever too soon. The bike lurched forward a little and I fell on my left side with the bike. While picking it up, it fell again on its right side. It was down for about 7 to 10 minutes before I got help picking it up.  Now it won't turnover at all or start.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Related (unsolved) question here: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/809/675

Answer (score 5):

## Background

So there is a grounding switch on your clutch lever, hence the need to pull in the clutch to start the motorcycle.

## Troubleshooting

You can disconnect that switch and get a piece of wire and complete the circuit at the connector.  Once that's done, make sure you're in neutral and then try to start the bike.
The switch is labeled 10 in the illustration below.

## Solution

If it starts, then you damaged the switch or connector when you dropped it.  Perhaps you pinched and cut one of the leads to the switch.

So if it starts check.
1.  The switch
2.  The connector
3.  The wiring attached to the connector.

The switch is $15 new and you can google "suzuki katana \model year\ oem parts" and get a bunch of hits for an online order.  Good luck!

[image]